# Google Compute engine and no files in bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I have a client and whoever designed their site put it in Compute Engine.  I am totally lost, no clue about this.  I do see a bucket but there is only a footer.php in it.  The site is a multi wordpress and I can not find where the files are stored or how to access phpmyadmin to see the database.

I ask this because the site is having many issues, starting with ssl expired, php is out of date and now I can not login or see the site because it is giving a 500 error or white page of death.
Tried to find what caused the error but nothing.

Site is http://nextstudy.org

Can anyone help or direct me on what I can do to get to the files and maybe get it off of compute engine?

Appreciate you reading this............
Diana

Comment: You can check the details on `Deployment Manager > Deployment > Click on the Wordpress deployment` then details will appear on the right side of the screen if they deployed it from the Marketplace. Otherwise, check `Compute Engine > VM Instance > SSH` if they manually set it up in GCE.

Comment: Thank you Alex, I will look into that.  I found the orginal developer but this site was created 5 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

GCE does not host files from a bucket, but it runs VM instances off disk images.

Unless being assigned an admin role in Cloud IAM, there's probably not much to do. And even with an admin role granted, it's still rather risky when having no clue, I mean, while it's only a single instance, Cloud Shell might help, but when it's an instance group, the deployment may work whole different (up until the point where the servers are spun up from nothing but a shell script, which subsequently makes editing individual instances quite meaningless).